# Are runway safety areas for both emergency landings and aborted take-offs?

Tags: landing, emergency

Is a runway safety area at the end of a runway provided specifically for safe emergency landing of aircraft using it and are required to abort takeoff just before or after reaching the critical V1 speed? Does it mean that at big international airports with a number of runways, each and every runway is to be provided with its own runway safety area?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the [runway safety area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway_safety_area) is to provide a buffer zone for aircraft that leave the runway for whatever reason, including rejecting a take-off late or by overshooting on landing. It's not specifically for an "emergency landing": sometimes the emergency might only arise during the course of the landing, for example tyres bursting or pilot error.

If it were only for emergency landings, then parallel runways probably wouldn't need to all have a RSA, because the distress aircraft could be offered the one runway that has one. But in fact *every* runway needs an RSA, because *any* landing might suffer a runway excursion.

Comment: There's also the point that an aircraft could develop an emergency while on final approach, in which case it wouldn't be ideal to abort the approach and set up a new one on the runway with the RSA

Comment: @JonStory, the approach was commenced to a long enough runway and that calculation was done for using brakes only, so the runway does not become too short when emergency develops. The runway end safety areas have nothing to do with existing emergencies.

Comment: @JanHudec Nothing I said suggested otherwise? I'm just pointing out that when you develop an emergency while on final, you'd appreciate the runway having an RSA - it would be unfortunate to be on short final to a runway without an RSA and have to decide between going around to set up on another runway, or land on a runway without an RSA. Nothing to do with existing emergencies

Comment: @JanHudec: "and that calculation was done for using brakes only" - Brakes _and spoilers_ (and airbrakes, too, if so equipped).